# Why would I have to trim a float to be able to match on it?

Tags: mysql

I have a few values in the database, in a FLOAT column that I want to search on.

Strangely, values of 2.5 come back when running this:

```
SELECT * from `prices` WHERE `price` = 2.5
```

But nothing is returned when I search on 4.8, UNLESS I do a trim on the column before comparing against it, like this:

```
SELECT * from `prices` WHERE trim(`price`) = 4.8
```

Anybody know what the cause of this might be, I thought that since it's a FLOAT field, there shouldn't be any leading or trailing space that needs to be trimmed. I'm assuming the number of 4.8 isn't anything special, but it's still intriguing.

When browsing the database, I can see it as a plain 4.8, with no leading or trailing characters.

I'm a bit stumped as to why this would be happening.

Comment: No direct answer: but floats are a weird thing; when you do the research one of the things you'll learn is that exact matches are completely unreliable and you should avoid them. I'm guessing you really want to use `DECIMAL` for something like a price. It's a really bad idea to rely on floats or doubles when working with prices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because 4.8 cannot be represented by a float. You can get values very close to it, but not the exact value.

I'm not entirely sure what trim is doing to it (I can't find anything specifying the behavior maybe it's not actually defined) but I know that it is changing the value so you can get a match. Read this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-float.html if you have further interest on the behavior of floats (although it won't tell you anything about what trim does to them).

Comment: trim is probably doing some ugly type coercion

Comment: Additional to this (after looking into it), it seems that DECIMAL has the same floating issues in versions 5.0.3 and lower

Comment: In place of moving to DECIMAL at this point in the game (we're already live) I'm changing the query to have round(`price`, 5) to try combat any differences down at the 10th decimal place

Comment: @duellsy That's probably a good approach. Later on you can move to storing it with two ints, one for the fractional part and one for whole numbers.